# Using JWT Bearer Authentication When Call API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt, http-headers

I want to access an API for a purchased product, I used the following code according to the product documentation:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com/api/login");

client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("username", "admin");
request.AddParameter("password", "admin");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

The documentation says:

> Authentication is performed via JWT Bearer
> Authentication. Every endpoint requires authentication, so you will
> need to add the following header to each request

```
Authorization: Bearer <JWT>
```

How can I add the JWT authentication in my upper request?

Comment: Can you please link the documentation? You very likely will **not be able to generate a JWT Bearer token using a username and password** as that is more suited for Basic authentication.

You will most likely need to call another auth endpoint first using your username and password, server will generate a bearer token, returns it and then you can use the token in subsequent requests to authorise your requests.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Here's the documentation, Please don't to select the c# from language list https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/11765341/U16byA2y

Comment: Thanks Abdulsalam! That helps, I've posted an answer - let me know if it puts you on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the *Access Granted Client Credentials* section of the [documentation you've provided](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/11765341/U16byA2y), the endpoint you need to be calling for a Bearer token is `/admin/api/index.php/api/login`.

Calling that endpoint with correct credentials will populate your `response.Content` with the below JSON:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9kZW1vNC5zYXNyYWRpdXMuY29tXC9hZG1pblwvYXBpXC9pbmRleC5waHBcL2FwaVwvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2MzA0MDU5OTgsImV4cCI6MTYzMDQwOTU5OCwibmJmIjoxNjMwNDA1OTk4LCJqdGkiOiJCZmdvN00zN2pkbGtRRzFhIiwic3ViIjoxLCJwcnYiOiJkNzk3N2M0N2U5MTY5NjUxMDEwNzM0ZDJmYmY4Y2MxMzlmM2U1MDM0In0.7tNWgF6psOPKpPC9-zU_hEK_GLx3-BeFlIW9LE4wzYo"
}
```

Deserialise the above JSON object to a token object & the `token` field will be your JWT token.

`Token.cs`

```
public class Token
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
}
```

```
var tokenObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(response.Content);
string token = tokenObj.token;
```

For subsequent requests, to authenticate, add this line & you should be good to go.

`request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");`

Comment: I got "Internal Server Error"

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif I can't help with more information but is your URL correct? Are your username and passwords correct? Your original question on how to set a bearer token on a RestSharp request has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {Token}");
```

Comment: How can I get the Token?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 